# Have to generate random numbers using java and pass the random numbers to xml variable. Also need to calculate additions of it

Tags: java, xml

Have to generate 3 random numbers using java and pass the generated values to the existing xml file variables.
And need to calculate addition and multiplication within xml file and need to print the value in the console.

Here I got the code for Random number generation. Could anyone help me on this?

```
package test_package;

import java.util.Random;

public class Random_Number_Generation {
    public static void main(String args [] ) {

        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
            int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
            System.out.print("\nRandom Number is :" + randomInt); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What help do you need?

Comment: I take it you need to do To XML ?

Comment: @ Naman gala I want code for the above. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example to create an xml using jaxb. In this example the methods:

`fromXml(String xml)` - will unmarshal the XML String to the XMLObj

`toXml(String xml)` - will  marshal the XMLObj to a String.

**The test class**

```
public class RandomNumberGen
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    RandomNumberGen randomNumberGen = new RandomNumberGen();
    String xml = randomNumberGen.doTheRandomToXml();
    System.out.println("The Original Value");
    System.out.println(xml);
    xml = randomNumberGen.addAnotherRandomNumber(xml);
    System.out.println("Added Another random val ");
    System.out.println(xml);

  }

  public String doTheRandomToXml()
  {
    XMLObj xmlObj = new XMLObj();
    xmlObj.setRandomNumberOne(getRandomNumber());
    xmlObj.setRandomNumberTwo(getRandomNumber());
    xmlObj.setRandomNumberThree(getRandomNumber());

    return toXml(xmlObj);
  }

  public String addAnotherRandomNumber(String xml)
  {
    XMLObj xmlObj = fromXml(xml);
    int numberOne = xmlObj.getRandomNumberOne();
    int numberTwo = xmlObj.getRandomNumberTwo();
    int numberThree = xmlObj.getRandomNumberThree();

    CalculatedValue calculatedValue = new CalculatedValue();
    calculatedValue.setCalculatedValue(numberOne + numberTwo - numberThree);
    calculatedValue.setValue(String.format("%s + %s - %s", numberOne, numberTwo, numberThree));

    xmlObj.setCalculatedValue(calculatedValue);
    return toXml(xmlObj);
  }

  private String toXml(XMLObj obj)
  {
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    try
    {
      JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(XMLObj.class);
      Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

      jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
      jaxbMarshaller.marshal(obj, stringWriter);

    }
    catch (JAXBException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return stringWriter.toString();
  }

  private XMLObj fromXml(String xml)
  {
    XMLObj xmlObj = null;
    try
    {
      StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
      JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(XMLObj.class);

      Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
      xmlObj = (XMLObj) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
    }
    catch (JAXBException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return xmlObj;
  }

  private int getRandomNumber()
  {
    int randomInt = 0;
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
      randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
    }
    return randomInt;
  }
}
```

**The XML Object class**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "xml-gen")
public class XMLObj
{
  private int number1;
  private int number2;
  private int number3;
  private CalculatedValue calculatedValue;


  public int getRandomNumberOne()
  {
    return number1;
  }

  @XmlElement
  public void setRandomNumberOne(int randomNumber1)
  {
    this.number1 = randomNumber1;
  }

  public int getRandomNumberTwo()
  {
    return number2;
  }

  @XmlElement
  public void setRandomNumberTwo(int randomNumber2)
  {
    this.number2 = randomNumber2;
  }

  public int getRandomNumberThree()
  {
    return number3;
  }

  @XmlElement
  public void setRandomNumberThree(int randomNumber3)
  {
    this.number3 = randomNumber3;
  }

  public CalculatedValue getCalculatedValue()
  {
    return calculatedValue;
  }

  public void setCalculatedValue(CalculatedValue calculatedValue)
  {
    this.calculatedValue = calculatedValue;
  }    
}
```

**The Calculated Value Class**

```
@XmlRootElement
public class CalculatedValue
{
  private int calculatedValue;
  private String calculation;

  @XmlAttribute
  public int getCalculatedValue()
  {
    return calculatedValue;
  }

  public void setCalculatedValue(int calculatedValue)
  {
    this.calculatedValue = calculatedValue;
  }

  @XmlValue
  public String getValue()
  {
    return calculation;
  }

  public void setValue(String calculation)
  {
    this.calculation = calculation;
  }
}
```

the output will look a like the following

```
The Original Value
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xml-gen>
    <randomNumberOne>51</randomNumberOne>
    <randomNumberThree>57</randomNumberThree>
    <randomNumberTwo>98</randomNumberTwo>
</xml-gen>

Added Another random Value
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xml-gen>
    <calculatedValue calculatedValue="92">51 + 98 - 57</calculatedValue>
    <randomNumberOne>51</randomNumberOne>
    <randomNumberThree>57</randomNumberThree>
    <randomNumberTwo>98</randomNumberTwo>
</xml-gen>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, This code works for me. I want to enhance this code like the XML file is already exists. In that 3 variable should be there. I have to generate 3 random numbers and need to pass random values to XML variable. Also the calculation should take place within the xml file. Could you please help me on this?

Comment: XML is a string so you cant calculate in the xml , however you can change the getter for `getRandomNumber()` call your random number generator method. *Also the calculation should take place within the xml file*  do you have a requirement for this , i take it this is homeowrk ?

Comment: 1. The requirement is like there will be 3 fields, randomly generated values has to entered into fields through a Test automation tool using java language. Based on this 3 values the fourth field will populate/calculate a value(Like addition,Multiplication ) We have to define the variable and also the formula in the XML file which is already exists with the project root folder. 2. Calculation within XML is possible by using Testng?

Comment: I don't understand this requirement ... *We have to define the variable and also the formula in the XML file which is already exists with the project root folder* Do you just need to display in the xml how the 4th value was calculated ?

Comment: Yes u r right we have to display the calculated value.Since its against Intellectual Property I'm not able to share the requirement here. We have an existing Project Area which as a XML file. Random Values has to passed and calculation has to be done.

Comment: Updated , please accept the answer if you are happy :)